# In Active Directory is it possible to specify which domain controller authenticates user?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I am troubleshooting why a user keeps getting locked out & think the issue might be on the Domain Controller. 
I've cleaned up lingering objects using the Lingering Object Liquidator but the issue is still occurring. 
Also deleted cached passwords using control userpasswords2, set CachedLogonsCount to 0 in the registry & enabled the group policy "Delete cached copies of roaming profiles". 
But the issue is still occurring. I've asked they end user if he is fat fingering his password & he's responded no. 
If I can force the user to authenticate to a specific domain controller this will provide information if the DC itself isn't functioning properly, since most of the lockout appear to be occuring on one domain controller. 
Thanks!

Comment: Sure... there are lots of ways to do that. One possible way would be to stop the KDC service on every other DC in the same site as the client.

Comment: Wouldn't that force all users to authenticate through the one DC? I don't want to bottleneck the organization - just one user on one workstation. thx!

Comment: Yes, it would funnel all the authentication traffic in that AD site through that one DC.

Comment: Please see this question Kearl http://serverfault.com/questions/664260/authenticate-client-against-specific-domain-controller

Comment: account lockout issue has nothing to do with lingering object. It is caused by one thing and one thing only: bad password. And when bad password is submitted, PDC is always be consulted. Follow MS' account lockout troubleshooting article, find out where the bad password is coming from. Common causes include orphaned RDP session, mapped drive using wrong pwd, services/scheduled task using wrong pwd,etc.

Comment: Thnks Art - I raised the priority value and lowered the weight value in the registry of the suspect DC so will see if the issue persists on the other DC.
Also I think it is an end user/client strongline but cannot isolate the issue & have cleared cached passwords on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more Sites there? Then you have to check the Site and Services Configuration.

[Site and Service Configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc731907.aspx)